# What light to use for my white background?

Tags: lighting, light, background, color-white

I have an inexpensive set of two lightboxes which I use to shoot a model for e-commerce images.

Generally, I use one lightbox to light the background and the other one for the subject. But there is no way I can get a clean white background or many times the background is white on the side where the light comes from but not on the other side.

What do you suggest to use to light a background at a budget?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if one side of the backdrop is getting more light than the other. **You just need to expose in such a way that the dimmest part of the backdrop is completely blown out.** You'll find this easiest to do if the flash lighting the backdrop is at full power (assuming it isn't too bright as to create a lot of spill back onto your subject). If the dimmest part of the backdrop is pure white in your resulting photo the entire backdrop will be pure white. There's no way for the brighter parts of the backdrop to be brighter or whiter than pure white in the resulting image.

Once you've got the exposure right for the backdrop you can then adjust the power of the other light to properly expose your subject at the same ISO and aperture.

Answer (score 0):

try placing the light box for the back drop at the feet of the model. pointing at the backdrop and that should take away the shadow affect

Answer (score 0):

You could add another inexpensive strobe like a Yongnuo.

You also could use a larger seamless white backdrop that is curved and perfectly smooth.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a matter of lighting ratios. Put the background light at full power, and find the narrowest aperture and lowest ISO where you're still completely blowing out the background. Keep the model forward and lit separately by your other flash much lower power.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute bargain basement budget, cheap, cheap, cheap...

One or more of those remote slave flashes that come with budget camera kits.

This [Godox](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Camera_Flash_CF_18.html) is one example, eBay have lots like it, usually from manufacturers you've never heard of. I've seen them as low as £4, but generally about 10-15 dollars/pounds/euros
No hot shoe or wireless trigger required;
They fire when they see your main flash fire.
No other timing/adjustment possible.
Weigh a couple of ounces.
Refresh times are usually bad, 5s or so.

You can put on a spare stand, using rubber bands if needs be, out of sight behind your model, pointing at the backdrop. BluTack/duck tape one to the model's back at a push, or get them to hold it.
If you need a diffuser... bubblewrap.

At best, it'll work well enough for you to consider upgrading to a better remote speedflash kit when you can afford it, at worst it was only a tenner.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of background is it? Cloth and seamless paper can be lit from behind if you are having problems positioning lights. You can also use flags (dark foam panels) to block excess light from hitting the model.

The best thing is to have enough room to move the model away from the background and then use two softboxes behind the model to light the bg. Then use one front softbox for the model.